# Execute keyEvent from java servlet

Tags: java, servlets, keypress, awtrobot

I wrote this little servlet, but it does not execute:
index.html
//Press button to call Servlet

```
<form method="post" name="postform" action="/WebApp/NewServlet">
```

web.xml

```
<servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.NewServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>NewServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/NewServlet</url-pattern>
```

NewServlet.java

//Servlet should execute keypress(just an example)

```
package javax;

import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


public class NewServlet extends HttpServlet {



    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        try {

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);

        } catch (AWTException ex) {
        }


    }

}
```

It compiles without errors but does not execute, please help before Im get nuts.
Maybe Java does not allow this action on Servlets or on post-actions?
But maybe you know another similar but working way, even if its not java.
maybe something "easier".

Comment: key events take place on client. servlets run on server. doing a keypress on the server doesn't affect client.

Comment: No, the the keyEvent should affect the server..

Comment: what are you really trying to do?

Comment: It should be an HTML-Client that should call the servlet on the server which executes the keyEvent. Just a little remote control for my htpc. THe  Keysequence is just an example, it can be Alt+f4, execute an Application or something else..